# How to create project for SXA themes in Helix-Habitat solution in SXA 9.3?

Tags: sxa, sxa-cli

We are creating a new project with `Sitecore SXA 9.3`. This project will have multiple sites and multiple themes also. We are creating a new solution by following Helix Principles. So let's say we have 3 sites and we want to have different `css/styles` for these sites. We want to create a theme by using SXA Creative exchange CLI. So How we can create this in our solution? Do we need to create multiple theme project for multiple themes? Or In one project can we maintain multiple themes?

Also, each theme has a separate `node_modules` folder. So do we need to maintain it separately?

Please provide the best practices for creating a theme project.

Comment: My first recommendation is to review how others have set up their projects for SXA. There are numerous blog posts about working with SXA and even a YouTube channel. Let Helix help you but don't let it cause analysis paralysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Helix we have Feature, Foundation, and Project folders. So we can use the Project folder to create a new project called Themes. Under that, we can put the Multiple Themes folder that is generated using SXA CLI.

If you are not aware of how to set up a theme folder then you can follow this link.

https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/sxa/93/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/add-a-theme-using-sxa-cli.html

Also, I don't think we need to create a separate node_modules folder for each theme. This folder will be used for dependencies to run the theme and each configuration of a particular theme is written under Theme gulp folder.